# Qlik Sense assigning user set

Tags: qliksense

I am new to Qlik Sense, and I have been assigned a task to divide users into two sets.

User Set A :

- These users can Create App, Load data, Create data models and create sheets over data model, so these users have the privilege to edit the sheet and data.

User Set B :

- These users can only Create and view sheets over data model or already created App. (limited privilege)

Any help or redirection to proper knowledge source is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this in the QMC( [Qlik Management Console](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense/3.1/Subsystems/ManagementConsole/Content/manage-site.htm),web-based application for configuring and administrating your Qlik Sense site ).

Before you do that is important that you understand the way it works:

- Access control is property-based.
- Security rules are inclusive by design.

Then leaveraging QMC proprieties:

In the QMC, you can create customized properties that you can connect to resources. The main purpose of custom properties is to use them in the security rules. You can also create and connect QMC tags that can be used for filtering on the overview page of a resource. Tags cannot be used in the security rules.

Examples of applications for custom properties:

**Grouping nodes by geography**

Create a custom property called Countries and set the values to names of countries. Apply the custom property to your nodes and you can then create and deploy synchronization rules / load balancing rules to countries instead of individual nodes.

**Grouping streams by department**

Create a custom property called Departments with values appropriate to your organization. Apply the custom property to your streams and you can then apply security rules to streams according to their Departments property instead of managing security rules for individual streams.

Your case is the second one, and you can refer to this **Access rights for user types**, I would go creating 2 groups:

Group A: Developers

Group B : Contributors

Indeed

**Developer** :  is allowed to create apps, sheets, stories, objects and can use and create data connections.

**Contributor**: is allowed to create stories and sheets for published apps but is not allowed to create new apps.

Here a general overview:

The following activities with corresponding access rights have been identified.
See table [here](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense/3.1/Subsystems/ManagementConsole/Content/apply-access-rights-for-user-types.htm)